# Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console. The error message was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'raise_error'

Tags: pandas, spyder, python-3.7, geopandas

I have been working on a project that deals with pandas and geopandas. But i came across an error with the last line. The .shp file is in my specified path and everything is fine. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd


from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()


data = pd.read_html(webpage)

for data_cases in data:
print(data_cases)

data_cases = data_cases[['Country,Other', 'TotalCases']]

world_data = gpd.read_file(r'/home/evans/Desktop/GIS DEVELOPMENTS/PROJECTS/World_countries/World_Countries.shp')
```

Everything executes well with no errors on the console. But when i try opening the variable *world_data*, in the variable explorer, I get the error:

```
Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console.

The error message was:
'tuple' object has no attribute 'raise_error'
```

I will appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Comment: I think this error is fixed in Spyder 4.1.1 and spyder-kernels 1.9.0. But it simply means that you can't open that variable because it can't serialized in the kernel.

Comment: So what can i do to make it work?

Comment: There's nothing to do, sorry.

Comment: Seems to be related to this issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11471