# Spyder 5 & Windows: Variable Explorer doesn't show pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, windows, ide, spyder

Windows 10, installed Python 3.10, then Spyder 5 from Windows Installer. Changed python interpreter (preferences) to the previously installed Python 10. Basically it works fine. However if I want to see in the Variable Explorer more complex objects like pandas dataframes, it gives back:

Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console. The error message was: ''

There is also no error message in the console

Without any error messages it's hard to trace back. Interesting enough, that pandas series are shown, data frames not. Any incompatibilites known between Spyder 5 and Python 3.10?

Any idea highly appreciated...

Comment: seems like a bug in spyder , report it to Spyder team and see what they say

Comment: Same issue. I think it is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918991/spyder-was-unable-to-retrieve-the-value-of-this-variable-from-the-console-the-e.                            But I haven`t found the way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading pandas worked for me. I had version 1.4.2 of pandas and the Spyder installer I used (5.15) had come with pandas version 1.3.3. I think that version of spyder isn't compatible with the newer pandas version so I downgraded the pandas package that's used in the python interpreter (not the one that comes with the installer)  to 1.3.3

You could also try different versions of the Spyder installer. A couple of the versions was giving me different problems and I found version 5.15 to be the sweet spot for my setup.

Comment: It's kind of funny that a year later I had a similar problem and google brought me back to my own answer. Still worked for me btw! This time the Spyder installer came with pandas 2.0 and my conda env had pandas 1.5.3. Updating pandas in my conda env to 2.0.0 made the variable explorer work.